# MySQL multidimensional arrays

Tags: mysql, multidimensional-array

What is the best way to store data that is dynamic in nature using MySQL?  Let's say I have a table in which one item is "dynamic".  For some entries I need to store one value, but for others it could be one hundred values.  For example let's say I have the following simple table:

```
CREATE TABLE manager
( 
name char(50),
worker_1_name(50),
worker_2_name(50),
...
worker_N_name(50)
);
```

Clearly, this is not an ideal way to set up a database.  Because I have to accommodate the largest group that a manager could potentially have, I am wasting a lot of space in the database.  What I would prefer is to have a table that I can use as a member of another table (like I would do in C++ through inheritance) that can be used by the "manager" table to handle the variable number of employees.  It might look something like this.

```
CREATE TABLE manager
( 
name char(50),
underlings WORKERS 
);

CREATE TABLE WORKERS 
( 
name char(50),
);
```

I would like to be able to add a variable number of workers to each manager.  Is this possible or am I constrained to enumerating all the possible number of employees even though I will use the full complement only rarely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you should be doing something like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE managers ( 
    manager_id int,
    name       char(50)
);

CREATE TABLE workers (
    name       char(50),
    manager_id int
);
```

This is how you should represent "a variable number of workers" in the [relation model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_model).

Comment: This is specifically [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).  It's mentioned in that relation model link, but it's a pretty large page to find it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an ID column to keep track of the workers as records in the same table.

```
CREATE TABLE manager
(
name char(50),
id int
);

CREATE TABLE WORKERS
(
managerID int,
name char(50)
);
```

Allow duplicate managerIDs in worker...when you want to get specific workers to a manager, simply SELECT Name FROM WORKERS where managerID=ID and it will return all of the workers for that manager. If you need more complex lookups you could also use Joins.

Answer (score 0):

You could assign an autoincrement id to manager, and link the workers to it using a foreign key:

```
manager
   id
   name

worker
   id
   manager_id
   name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an intermediate mapping table. Something like the following:

```
manager(id, name)
managerWorkerMapping(managerId, workerId)
worker(id, name)
```

Now, to get all of the workers for a particular manager, you can run the following query:

```
select w.name from worker w, manager m, managerWorkerMapping mwm
where m.name = 'manager name' and
      m.id = mwm.managerid and
      mwm.workerId = w.id
```

It's important to note that with this schema, it's possible for workers to have multiple managers as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
select w.name from worker w, manager m, managerWorkerMapping mwm
where m.name = 'manager name' and
      m.id = mwm.managerid and
      w.id = mwm.workerId
```

Comment: Could you provide some explanation to go with this? What you've done that's fundamentally different and why it's solution for the OP?

Comment: @cliff -- while the query statement is helpful, consider adding this to the existing answer. By itself it does not answer the question posed by the OP.

Comment: Exact duplicate of [the other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2433788/1402846).